# Is there support for distributor server failover?

Tags: availability-groups, transactional-replication, failover

I have done googling for this question. The answer is no. But the answer is on year 2015. How about now? Is the distributor server have failover support capibility?

Answer (score 1):

For a distribution database to support SQL Server replication? Yes, there are supported scenarios detailed here, along with limitations and exclusions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/configure-distribution-availability-group?view=sql-server-2016